# Put automatic heading on top of table

Tags: php

I have this code that will generate a table of years that is split into groups of 5 years each..from 2006 to 2017

How do I put a heading on top of the table as example below..

```
    <?php
      $chunkSize = 5;
      $starting_year  = 2006;
      $ending_year    = date("Y");
      //create an array of years
      $years = range($starting_year,$ending_year); 
      //[2006,2007,....,2016,2017]

      //split years in required size
      $chunked = array_chunk($years,$chunkSize);
      //[ [2006,....,2010], [2011,...2015], [2016,2017]]

      //reverse it
      $reversed = array_reverse($chunked); 
      //[ [2016,2017], [2011,...2015], [2006,....,2010]]


      foreach($reversed as $reverse) {
      echo "<b>Year $year</b>";
         echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'><tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
        foreach($reverse as $year) {
          echo "<th>{$year}</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        foreach($reverse as $year) {
          $result= $myDB->query("SELECT total FROM ".$myDB->prefix("statistics")." WHERE year='{$year}'") or die(mysql_error());
          echo "<td>{$result['total']}</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody></table>";
      }
```

current output

```
**Year 2017**
2016    2017            
total  total   

**Year 2017**
2011    2012    2013    2014    2015
total  total   total    total  total

**Year 2015**
2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
total  total   total    total  total
```

Desired output

```
**Year 2016-2017**
2016    2017            
total  total  

**Year 2011 - 2015**      
2011    2012    2013    2014    2015
total  total   total    total  total

**Year 2006 - 2010**
2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
total  total   total    total  total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, isn't the simple solution just:

```
echo "<b>Year {$reverse[0]}-{$reverse[count($reverse)-1]}</b>";
```

You want to output the first and last elements of the `$reverse` array.

Comment: Thank you..but its not working..i got a half loading page

Comment: Oops, I had `$count` instead of `count` - was my typo the problem?

Comment: Yes thanks again..now its working.. im still a beginner..you really helped me a lot. Have a nice day